# VS2013 / C# Console Output Scrambled

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, console

I have a program that calls this method about 100x in a loop:

```
 private void writeLog (string text)
    {
        txtConsole.AppendText(text);
        txtConsole.AppendText(System.Environment.NewLine);
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        Console.WriteLine(System.Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

`txtConsole` is a standard multiline TextBox. I would expect that after this loop is ran, both `txtConsole` and the standard Console would have the same contents. What I am seeing is that the standard Console is a jumbled mess.

Here is an example of the end of `txtConsole` after the loop (which is what I want):

```
SFB239
Name:   FUNC
Family: SBUS    
Author: 
Load Size:  108
SFB240
Name:   DPRAM   
Family: SBUS    
Author: 
Load Size:  112
```

The output in the standard console is:

```
Author: 
SFB54


Name:   RALRM
```

The text in the standard console is bits and pieces of what it should have (but much earlier in the loop). Everything is being called synchronously, but its almost list the console is being written to asynchronously, and strings are overwriting each other.

Comment: I don't think you need Console.WriteLine(System.Environment.NewLine);... Console.Writeline() already ends with a new line.

Comment: Agree wit Shar1er80.  When you are AppendText the text is going off the left side of the console window and you are not seeing all the text.  Either perform a writeLine("") with no data or add a '\n' to the end of the text.

Comment: I'm using AppendText for the TextBox, which is working, and WriteLine for the standard Console, which isn't.

Comment: Do you call writelog in a parralel or multithread process ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, the text I was writing to the console contained lots of unprintable low ASCII characters. Once I sanitized the text by replacing those characters with String.Empty, it worked correctly.